# Slow mongodb queries

Tags: mongodb, performance, numpy, mongodb-query

I have a collection of ~300,000 documents, and I need to make about ~150,000 queries. I have matrix A_B (150,000 rows, A column, B column), and I need to query for the B entry in each row, find the document associated with this entry, and its value, 'C_id.' Then I keep track of all A values and associated C values in matric A_C (150,000 rows, A column, C column).
Currently, this takes over an hour to run, which seems absurdly slow. Any ideas as to why it's so slow? Every time, cursor should return a single document.

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = client.dataBases
collection = db.collection

A_B = np.loadtxt('A_B.txt')
A_C = np.zeros(A_B.shape)

for r in range(0, A_B.shape[0]):
    A = A_B[r, 0]
    B_r = A_B[r, 1]
    C = 0
    cursor = collection.find({'C_id': B_r})
    for i in cursor:
        C = i['n_id']

    A_C[r, :] = np.asarray([A, C])

np.savetxt('A_C.txt', A_C.txt)
```

Comment: what indexes do you have on those collections?

Comment: I let mongodb generate IDs automatically. Could that be a problem?

Comment: that shouldn't be problem generally

Comment: Is this the sort of the speed I should expect?

Comment: There are many things that can affect performance, not just the database itself. You could start by reading [MongoDB Performance](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/analyzing-mongodb-performance/). For a start, you should have index for field `C_id` on the collection and make sure it fits nicely in RAM. Having said the above, it would help if you could post example documents and contents of the variables. See also related [query explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/)

Comment: One document looks like the following: { "_id" : ObjectId("58ed456c4d258eb9314272e8"), "n_id" : 187555, "address" : "1P8JEyFzdmWcTEkYGhnXCHDDHkGtMhvrS3" }